# css mistake under zoom

Tags: html, css

Hello people i stick on a problem
i have a header with no zoom on 100% it look like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8tp8.png

but when i zoom the header goes right :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BapBA.png

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
<div id="logo"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**css:**

```
body {
background:url(images/bg.png);
margin:0;
padding:0;}

#header {

margin-bottom:170px;
background:url(images/headerBg.png);
height:386px;
width:100%;}

#header #logo{
min-width:990px;
height:207px;
width:990px;
background:url(images/logo.png);
margin:0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `min-width` to you `body` as per your page width. Write like this:

```
body{
 min-width:990px;
}
```